# Entity Framework Circular Reference in same table with both required

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first, one-to-one

I want to have pair of rows for every transfer which are poi
I have:

```
public class Transfer :  DependentRestrictedEntity 
{
    public virtual Account Acount { set; get; }
    public DateTime Time { set; get; }  
    public Transfer PairedTransfer { set; get; }
    [NotMapped]
    public override RestrictedEntity DependentOn => Acount;
    //other code.
}

public class Account : RestrictedEntity
{        
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //other code.
}

 public class RestrictedEntity : Entity
{
    public Filter Filter { get; set; }
    //other code.
}

public abstract class DependentRestrictedEntity : RestrictedEntity
{
    [NotMapped]
    public abstract RestrictedEntity DependentOn { get; } 
    //other code.
}

 public class Entity
{
    [Key, JsonProperty, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid ID { set; get; }
    //other code.
}

 public class MyMoneyContext : UserDbContext
{
    public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Transfer> Transfers { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder _modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(_modelBuilder);


        _modelBuilder.Entity<Transfer>()
           .HasRequired(_t => _t.PairedTransfer)
           .WithRequiredDependent();
    }
    //other code
}
```

Somehow I need pair 2 Transfers. One of them should belong to 1st account, and second one should belong to 2nd account. User which have permissions to first account but do not have permission to second account should not be able to see both of those entries.

Problem here is that that I do not know how to add new entry. I tried:

```
var accounts = Database.Accounts.ToList();
Transfer pair, pair2;
Database.Transfers.Add(
    pair = new Transfer()
    {
        ID = Guid.NewGuid(),
        Ammount = 100,
        Filter = accounts[0].Filter,
        Acount = accounts[0],
    }
);

Database.Transfers.Add
(
    pair2 = new Transfer()
    {
        ID = Guid.NewGuid(),
        Ammount = -100,
        Filter = accounts[1].Filter,
        Acount = accounts[1],
    }
);
pair.PairedTransfer = pair2;
pair2.PairedTransfer = pair;

Database.SaveChanges();
```

But I am getting circular Reference  problem.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that EF does not know which Transfer add to the DB first, because 1. have reference to 2. and 2. have reference to 1. (so it can't assign foreign keys)

I recommend to insert first transfer with null PairedTransfer, then insert second with assigned first PairedTransfer, then finally assign to second transfer to first's PairedTransfer :)

Comment: I understand what is the problem, I just do not know how to solve it.
But both are required (not null), so I do not know how to add one row with null?

Comment: Oh now I see you use the fluent API to state that PairedTransfer is Required... so in that case you can use some "dummy" Transfer that will have the role of a null (just for this purpose). Or if you can, just don't state it as required.

Comment: And how to create 1st dummy object. Maybe that object can to reference itself? Can I somehow say that all of that is in 1 transaction? I do not want to leave db inconsistent.

Comment: I'm not really sure if that will work, just try to reference itself and write the result :)
And yes you can use context.Database.BeginTransaction()) to do it in 1 transaction

Comment: Self reference had worked. But anyway I would like to find some better solution.

Comment: Better solution is to change your data model. It is strange to have entity that does have same entity as required property.